# JFrame appears with different size

Tags: java, swing

[image]

[image]

I have the following code

```
package trtyhard;    

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class TrtyHard {

     public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("TryHard");
                //frame.setSize(700, 500);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.setSize(700, 500);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);               
            }
        });          

    }       

}
```

Sometimes JFrame appears with diffirent size. Sometimes it has 10 additional mm at the bottom, sometimes 5-7 additional mm at the right side.
How can i fix it?

Comment: It sometimes appears as a different size even when running exactly the same code on the same computer?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot to show this?

Comment: GUIs should be created and launched on the EDT.

Comment: I added screenshorts

Comment: `setResizable` does some strange things and needs to be called at the right moment, usually before you apply the size of the window

Answer (score 2):

In addition to making sure the GUI is created on the `Event Dispatch Thread EDT)` try restructuring the code as follow:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("TryHard");
//frame.setSize(700, 500);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setSize(700, 500);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

The point is to set the frame properties before you do a setSize() or pack() on the frame.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial [Initial Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more information about the `EDT`.

Answer (score 0):

The JFrame class has the setBounds(x, y, width, height) method. You can try it. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)